# Django: How to edit model without PK in URL?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm writing a multiuser app, the problem is if I Edit a Product I have the URL:

```
re_path(r'backend/produkter/edit/(?P<artikel_id>[0-9]+)/$', backend_views.edit_artikel_view),
```

Which results:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/produkter/edit/36/
```

Now another User can use this URL because he is authenticated, and it looks not clean to me. Is it possible to go from view / url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/produkter/
```

to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/produkter/edit/
```

and give the ID on another way to the editView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to do in your requested format is to use Django Session.

Flow will be like this:

1. When you click Edit Product, make a post request to the same view with parameter as 'edit_product_id' and value as selected product's id
2. Set session variable for edit_product_id in the same view function like this:

```
edit_product_id = request.POST.get('edit_product_id')
request.session['edit_product_id'] = edit_product_id
```

after this redirect to the editView

3. On product editView, retrieve the edit_product_id and use it to update the databse.

```
edit_product_id = request.session.get('edit_product_id')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this makes sense, but the 'product_id' are already rendered in the html template (table with edit button) I need to pass it again to the view which again going throug kwarg / url or is there something I miss in my head? (Added my view)

Comment: This 'edit_product_id ' will be a hidden parameter in a post request. So, It is not going to show up in URL. If you want to do permission checking, you can do that while setting the session parameter in 2nd step. If someone tries to access 3rd step and session key is not set, then you should through a permission error.

Comment: Your edit button will be wrapped inside a form like this: <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}<input type="hidden" name="edit_product_id" value="{{ product.id }}"><button type="submit">Edit</button></form> In your editView URL you do not need to get the product_id because you will get it from session instead.

Comment: Thank you I tried it, and the session is saved fine after the I press the button, but in the edit view then the value is None, I tried to remove the .get in your 3. command: request.session('edit_product_id') but then I got error: 'SessionStore' object is not callable
Did I miss something?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. It should be request.session['edit_product_id'] But it will through error if you don't set edit_product_id in session properly.

Comment: Also try to print edit_product_id in second step to make sure it is not none

Comment: In 2nd Step the edit_product_id is not empty its 36 but in the edit view its empty. This makes it empty: request.session['edit_product_id '] = edit_product_id: here is it 36 edit_product_id = request.POST.get('edit_product_id') print(edit_product_id)

Comment: Make sure your are using the right key - "edit_product_id". Also, print request.session.get('edit_product_id') in the second step to check if session is saved or not.

Comment: print(request.session.get('edit_product_id')) is also in 2nd step empty :(

Comment: I see. Do you have django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware in the settings.py MIDDLEWARE? Refer this to know how to use sessions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Also, you can try request.session.save() after setting the key.

Comment: Settings are fine I checked it twice and the session.save() I tried also, same with session.update=True nothing helps :(

Comment: Maybe you can remove the space in your code so the next developer will not step in the same trap: request.session['edit_product_id '] = edit_product_id
 should be request.session['edit_product_id'] = edit_product_id

Comment: Lol. Sorry, I was not expecting that. I updated it. I need some coffee too. I am glad it's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If this product can not be modified by another user, then for sure this will be related with the logged-in User somehow.

1.) In that case, you don't need pk. Instead you can get the user info in the View itself from `request.user`, and now you can fetch the product you want to edit for this user. In this case your url will be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/produkter/edit
```

2.) Second way can be to check the user logged in and compare it with the product user, this can be done with request.user. Something like this :

```
if request.user.id == product.user.id:
```

considering you have the this relationship between user and product.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, for more details, if I have list with products which was created, how can I load the form instance without providing the pk in the url? url /backend/produkter/ is the list of products and the /backend/produkter/edit should be the form instance of the choosen product

Comment: If there is a relationship between product and user then list those product only which are related with that user... and also second method best suits in your case for multiple product. i.e. `if request.user.id == product.user.id:`